# Yii Undefined offset: 0 Using Query builder

Tags: yii, undefined, offset

It give error with this code:

```
   $checklist = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
      ->select('indicators, conditions, values, description')
      ->from('indicator')
      ->where([':indicators' => $kl_indicators[$i]])
     ->limit(1)
     ->queryAll();
```

"PHP notice: 
Undefined offset: 0"

what is wrong with that code? Help please.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your params are wrong. It should be:

```
->where('indicators=:in', [':in'=>$kl_indicators[$i]] )
```

or:

```
->where('indicators = "'.$kl_indicators[$i].'"')
```

---

See the [official API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#where()-detail) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found this answer:

```
    $checklist = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('id,conditions,indicators, values, description') //
    ->from('indicator')
    //->group('indicators')
    ->order('id ASC')
    ->where('indicators=:indicators', [':indicators'=>$kl_indicators[$i]])
    ->queryAll();
```

Thank you Samuel Liew, i need all rows so i use queryAll().